# Activate input field from input checkbox

Tags: html, forms, input, label, field

I want to activate the input field from checking the checkbox.

I have a basic form here:

```
<ul>
 <li>
  <label id="form-title" for="name3">Specifics:</label>
 <li>   
  <textarea id="name3" name="name3" >

  </textarea>
 </li>

</ul>
```

You click on the "Specifics and it activates the field. Can this be done with an input tag instead of a label tag?

Example:

```
<ul>
 <li>   
  <input type="checkbox" for="name2">Other...</input>
  <input id="name2" name="name2" />
 </li>
</ul>
```

jsfiddle of complete work thus far: http://jsfiddle.net/Sederu/gaZDW/

Comment: Are you talking about enabling and disabling the textarea on checkbox check and uncheck?

Comment: In the first case I used a textarea, but in this situation I need it for a input box (what you get if you just but '<input></input>'). So you check the box for "other" and that activates the input field.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You will need a little EMCAScript for that.

```html
<label for="name3">
      <input type="checkbox" id="name3activaitor" onclick="if(this.checked){ document.getElementById('name3').focus();}" />
      Other...
    </label>
<input type="text" id="name3" name="name3" />
```

The inline handler sees if the checkbox has been checked, and if it has, focuses the text input. I put the checkbox in the label just to symantically group it with the label as it preforms the same function, but you can put the checkbox anywhere you would like.

If you are looking to enable/disable the input field rather than just focus it, you can do like so

```html
<input type="checkbox" onclick="var input = document.getElementById('name2'); if(this.checked){ input.disabled = false; input.focus();}else{input.disabled=true;}" />Other...
<input id="name2" name="name2" disabled="disabled" />
```

Comment: So there is no possible way to do this with just html?

Comment: I got the first javascript to work, but couldn't get the second one to work. What does it do differently? What do you mean by enable/disable?

Comment: It looks like I left out a couple of quotation marks in my hurried typing the other day. The second snippet should work now.

Comment: The second piece of code, doesn't just focus the input element when the checkbox is clicked. It also sets the html disabled attribute on and off so that if the checkbox is not clicked, the input is disabled (cannot be focused and will not be submitted with the form) and enables the input if the checkbox is checked so that it can have text entered into it and will be submitted in that case.

Comment: That's awesome! Tried the second snippet, worked, thanks Reid!

Comment: Well it almost works. right when the page loads you can type in the field. but once you check it and then uncheck it you can't. So the only time you can't type in that field is after you have checked it. Any ideas to fix that so it doesn't let you type in it at all until you have checked it?

Comment: I feel a little foolish, I've been running on about 30 min of sleep because my 8 month old daughter hasn't been sleeping lol. I have edited the second code snippet and run it through your fiddle to make sure everything is correct this time. You shouldn't have any further issues with that snippet.

Comment: That did it! Thank you so much! Sorry for taking time away from your daughter. That's awesome that you stay up for her, need more dads like you in this world.

Comment: Hi, Thanks you for this code! This still works even on 2017! I am saddened though as there are no css html5 alternative. Hope we get one soon!

Answer (score 4):

The attribute for doesn't exist for input tag. For your purpose, use inline javascript code and attribute disabled:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" onclick="if (this.checked){ document.getElementById('textarea1').removeAttribute('disabled');}" />
<textarea id="textarea1" name="textarea1" disabled></textarea>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with little javascript,

**HTML**

```
<ul>
 <li>   
  <input type="checkbox" id="checker" for="name2">Other...</input>
  <input id="name2" name="name2" />
 </li>
</ul>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
document.getElementById('checker').onchange = function() {
 if(this.checked==true){
  document.getElementById("name2").disabled=false;
  document.getElementById("name2").focus();
 }
 else{
  document.getElementById("name2").disabled=true;
 }
};
```

Hope it will help

Answer (score -1):

All of the other answers work, but this one is simple::

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox"><label class="checkbox" for="checkbox"> Remember Me!
```

Explanation:

- `<input` defines the tag calling.
- `type="checkbox"` defining it is a checkbox.
- `id="checkbox">` identifying it as "checkbox".
- `<label class="checkbox"` classifying it as "checkbox".
- `for="checkbox">` calls that id "checkbox"
- `Remember Me!` What it says beside the checkbox.